# Mathjs eval function behaving differently with and without string

Tags: javascript, typescript, eval, arithmetic-expressions, mathjs

When I am evaluating Arithmetic operation without quotes in math.eval function null is ignored and I get proper results.
Where as if I put quotes to same function it throws error.

Problem is I cannot work without string, as I have some custom functions which cannot be processed without quotes.

I am using mathjs ***version 4.0.1.***

[image]

Comment: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `math.eval(100+null)`, the expression `100+null` is evaluated before the `.eval()` function is called. `100+null` (as a plain JavaScript expression) evaluates to 100. When you pass a  string, you're asking the Mathjs expression parser to evaluate the expression, and clearly it considers `'100+null'` to be a syntax error; there is no `null` constant in the Mathjs expression syntax.